# Bootstrap 3 - Move item up from the row below

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, grid

I have three sections on my site; lets call them V, D and H. On large screen display this looks like:

```
vvvdd
vvvdd
vvvdd
hhhhh
hhhhh
```

However on medium desktop it looks like this, with a load of white space:

```
vvvd
vvvd
vvvd
   d
   d
   d
hhh
hhh
hhh
```

How do I move the H block up on desktop view to fill the space?

```
vvvd
vvvd
vvvd
hhhd
hhhd
hhhd
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.

For reference, here's the site: http://garemoko.github.io/hosanna/kids/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can try to achieve it with a combination of bootstrap grid classes and custom positioning. For example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="v col-sm-7 col-xs-9">V</div>
        <div class="d col-sm-5 col-xs-3">D</div>
        <div class="h col-sm-12 col-xs-9">H</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    position: relative;
}
.row .d {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

I used `col-xs-` and `col-sm-` classes for demo, you may need to change them accordingly.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/Oez9D58JhHcwMdyWLZXU?p=preview

Comment: Thank you - this helped me to get to a resolution. A few extra things that helped me but maybe weren't clear in the original question: 1. position:relative was not required as bootstrap already supplies this. 2. I had to remove bottom:0 to make D the size of the content and no bigger 3. This broke smaller layouts (I was using a large and medium screen) so I used media queries to apply the fix only to that screen size.